# Fixed length bit arrays in Python

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

I am learning about bitwise operations and working through some practice problems on the subject.  The book I am working with assumes fixed-length byte arrays.  My programming language of choice (Python) uses variable-length byte arrays.

Do bitwise operators always produce the same output under Python's variable-length binary representation of integers as they would if integers had a fixed-length binary representation?

One exception I can think of is the `<<` operator because it loses information when byte arrays have fixed length, but does not lose information in Python:

```
In [132]: bin(8)
Out[132]: '0b1000'

In [133]: bin(8 << 1)
Out[133]: '0b10000'

In [134]: bin(8 << 1 >> 1)
Out[134]: '0b1000'
```

Are there other exceptions?

Comment: You have to refer to the exact definition of shift operations, but as Python doesn't have a limit (save of course memory), it will behave like bitwise operations over natural numbers, not like those over limited-range integers. That said, I don't understand how or why your example demonstrates some kind of exception, nor how anything there relates to byte arrays.

Comment: Yes, that is another way to explain my question.  In other words, how exactly are these two worlds different and when can I expect the same results from bitwise operators?  The example above is an exception because the `<<` operator loses information in a fixed-length world.  Bits fall off the left edge and it is impossible to recover them.  So, if numbers were represented by four bits `8<<1` would equal `0`.